# HTML/CSS Safari block not visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, cross-browser

I'm having a bit of a layout issue with Safari and can't seem to figure out what is going on.

**Case:**
Layout: `fixed` top header and a `fixed` sidebar stretching from top to bottom.

The sidebar navigation has a hover element which is triggered using Javascript.

**Issue:**
When hovering over the nav bar the hover works, but the hovered item is not visible (check screenshot).

[Image of triggerd navigation item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbREv.png)

This **only** happens in Safari, even in IE11 it works.

**Options tried:**

- `z-index` on the hovered item;
- changing the display mode;
- changing the `ul` into a `div`;
- re-applying a `background` to the item;
- changed `overflow` to `visible` on multiple items;
- added `opacity` to 'opened' navigation block.

html (not triggerd by Javascript):

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="navigation--dropdown-trigger" href="#">
      <svg class="icon navigation--icon">
        <use href="#icon--user" xlink:href="#icon--user"/>
      </svg>
      <div class="navigation--text">Admin</div>
      <svg class="icon navigation--dropdown-icon">
        <use href="#icon--arrow" xlink:href="#icon--arrow"/>
      </svg>
    </a>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="{{ route('users.index') }}">Gebruikersbeheer</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

html (triggerd by Javascript):

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="navigation--dropdown-trigger open--dropdown" href="#">
      <svg class="icon navigation--icon">
        <use href="#icon--user" xlink:href="#icon--user"/>
      </svg>
      <div class="navigation--text">Admin</div>
      <svg class="icon navigation--dropdown-icon">
        <use href="#icon--arrow" xlink:href="#icon--arrow"/>
      </svg>
    </a>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="{{ route('users.index') }}">Gebruikersbeheer</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This runs the following css (using scss btw):

```
&.navigation--dropdown-open ~ ul
{ display: block; }
```

**Notes:**

- When the Javascript is triggerd it adds a `top:` value to the ul as well.
- If I remove `position: fixed` of the dropdown ul, it does appear inside the sidebar [image: Visible submenu hover item]
- The above screenshot also applies when removing the `left:` value from the dropdown.

My colleague found this on the [Apple site (2014)](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5495621) with an example Fiddle, if you open it in Safari you can see the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/m287S/1/

Anyone have an idea why it's not visible?

Comment: Hi does the `<svg>` at least render?

Comment: Yes, the `<svg>` is the icon (user). The other `<svg>` is hidden in this specific view.

Comment: It's weird... from the Fiddle you shared it seems like a _Safari_ bug...

Comment: Yea it seems to look like it... However the Fiddle I shared is from an Apple bug report from 2014 ='D...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually figured out that Safari can't handle `overflow` on `absolute` positioned elements. So I've eventually ended up rewriting the main navigation, now it works.